# Little and Big Endian access on boards with multiple devices - Embedded software architecture

Tags: c, embedded-linux, endianness, vxworks

We have several boards, think of them as motherboards.
These motherboard contains different devices from microprocessors,ASICs and FPGAs...
So far all the devices are 16 bit Big endian based.
The problem at the moment is that we're using a new ASIC that is 32 little endian based while all other devices on the mobo are big endian.
We have created specific apis to read/write 32 bit little endian.
In the future we might have mobo's that can have a mixture of devices using 16/32 Big/little endian. These same devices could be used on different new or old mobos.

We use Embedded C (in Vxworks)as the language and our software is modularized to use common code and mobo specific code.
Solutions of using #defines and checking #ifdef have arrised but I'm not entirely sure how to go with them.
We can't really use #ifdef on the processor type because that same processor could be used on a different mobo with different access requirements.

I would greatly appreciate some help architecturally and right down technically in terms of a sample C code example if possible.

Comment: If you're running Linux on the system, you can use the 'endian conversion' functions provided by the system: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/be16toh.3.html  If you're not running Linux, I'd consider implementing those same functions for your target (they're not very complex functions).

Comment: It's not a question of the availability or the use of the conversion functions.It's about how to know when to use either kind given that each device on the mobo could need a different endian access.

Comment: You only need to worry about endianess of the data you're accessing when the data is some sort of serialized stream that comes from or will be read by another device.  In that case the data stream should always be little endian or big endian according to the stream's spec (for example, TCP streams are always big endian, also known as network byte order).  Then you use the conversion function to read the fields of the stream - if the data already matches the host's byte order then the function becomes a no-op.

Comment: For example, if you have a data stream with little endian fields, then your code would read a 32-bit field using `le32toh()` regardless of whether the platform is big endian or little endian. On a little endian platform that function will be a no-op, on a big endian platform the function will swap the bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Write an API for your device.

The API will provide a guarantee that it will accept data from the microprocessor in the microprocessor's byte order, and return data to the microprocessor in the microprocessor's byte order.  Then the API does the LE->BE or whatever conversion.

At the least, you'd have `asic_read32` or `fpga_read16`, for instance.  Your `asic_read32()` function would be like this:

```
/* asic is little endian */
asic_read32(...)
    if microprocessor is big endian  /* do this at compile time with #if */
        le_data = read32_le(...)
        return to_big_endian(le_data)
    else
        return read32_le(...)
```

And your microprocessor app happily ignores that any of this is going on:

```
uin32_t num_bytes_frobbed = asic_read32(BYTES_FROBBED_REG);
printf("Frobbed %u bytes so far.\n", num_bytes_frobbed);
```

As a bonus, all access to your device will go through a single API, so you can put in locks if necessary to make device access multithread safe.

If you feel comfortable with it and it's appropriate, you might be able to abstract out the device itself and implement a higher-level functions like `get_frobbing_statistics(struct frobbing_stats *stats)`.

Comment: This idea is almost correct, except the OP specifically said that he doesn't want to use preprocessor. It would be better if endianess was detected at system init time and then use a runtime conditional in the *_read32() functions and the like.